# Setting Aurora Read replica consistency parameter in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am setting up multi-region and for that I am using AWS Aurora, with primary cluster in one region(reader-writer) and secondary cluster having only reader instance
Now, reader instance has write-forwarding on to support DML queries on secondary instance. For that we need to set up
set aurora_replica_read_consistency = 'session',
for each session according to AWS docs
If we try to setup this parameter on writer, this will give error
Is there any way we can set this parameter for each DB session on reader instance in configuration?
Otherwise, I need to use
DB::statment('set aurora_replica_read_consistency = "session"');
whenever I am making a DB connection
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPpqf.png)

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Do you have code examples on what you have tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72206971/whats-a-proper-way-to-set-aurora-replica-read-consistency-in-django
Please refer this, I am looking for similar functionality in PHP, 
where I should be able to set parameter during DB connection only, currently I am embedding the db statement code everywhere before DML query is being performed.
Is there any way where I can directly specify at DB config level in PHP/ laravel to set the parameter every time a DB connection is made